# Learning resources for developing custom TinkerPop Vertex Programs

Tags: graph, resources, gremlin, tinkerpop, vertex

I have read the TinkerPop official docs and provided tutorials on their website. I am looking for further learning resources on developing custom Vertex Programs that cover the fundamentals and anatomy of such programs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many resources on this topic. Generally speaking you should be comfortable in your understanding of [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel), which is the general processing model that [GraphComputer](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphcomputer) is built on and you should look at the code for the various [VertexProgram implementations](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_a_collection_of_vertexprograms) that already exist in TinkerPop. Finally, I wrote a [tutorial](https://stephen.genoprime.com/snippet/2020/09/26/snippet-13.html) on this topic which might be helpful which was inspired by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63972067/1831717).